# Good way of encrypting org-gcal credentials

Tags: gpg, org-gcal

New to emacs. Looking for a good solution for encypting org-gcal client-id and client-secret in my .spacemacs config file.

Here is the current line in user-config (obscuring private information):

```
  (setq org-gcal-client-id "i-like-spinach-pizza.com"
        org-gcal-client-secret "dont_you?"
        org-gcal-fetch-file-alist `(("wealldo@hotmail.com" . "~/Dropbox/org/exclude-beorg/cal-gmail.org")))
```

Thank you!